# Spring MVC bean validation issue

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I have 2 bean as follows. Student bean validation is fine. But the inner bean `Address` validation has no effect at all. Although there is no validation for `Address.pincode`, but comes validation message as `studentAddress.pincode Value must be an integer`.
Why is it happening? Well I'm new in Spring, pleas explain in details. Thanks in advance!

```
public class Student {

@Size(min=2, max=30)
private String studentName;

@Size(min=3, max=30)
private String studentHobby;
@NotNull
private int studentMobile;

@Past
private Date studentDOB;
private ArrayList<String> studentSkills;

private Address studentAddress;
}

public class Address {

@Size(min=4, max=50)
private String country;

@Size(min=4, max=50)
private String city;

private String street;
private int pincode;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `pincode` being posted from the browser when the exception occurs?

Comment: That isn't even a validation message but data binding message which happens before. The value of the request parameter `studentAddress.pincode` must be an integer value not empty not abc but 1. If it can be null make it an `Integer` instead of primitive `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using using Hibernate Validator 4.0.0+, you can do a "cascade validation" like so :

```
@Valid
private Address studentAddress;
```