# Spring Validation-API on Custom Object

Tags: json, spring, validation, request

I'm using the Validation Annotation API to validate a Request for one of my REST Api entry point. They look like these

```
public class AddPlaceRequest {

   @NotEmpty
   private String name;

   @NotEmpty
   private String address;

   @NotNull
   private CoordinateModel coordinateModel

}

public class CoordinateModel {

  @NotNull 
  private Double coordX
  @NotNull
  private Double coordY

}
```

But If I try to pass this JSON for example, which contains coordX null

{"name":"test", "address":"test2", "coordinateModel" : {"coordX" : null, "coordY: 0.0}}

The NotNull validation of the coordX doesn't seem to be kicking in?

ps: it works for name and address, if one of those fields are empty or null the validation raises and exception.

Could someone explain why the validation annotation NotNull doesn't work on my custom Coordinate Object ?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to add `@Valid` for nested components.

Comment: Duplicate Question . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839538/spring-mvc-bean-validation-issue